# Grails domain mapping exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

After running fine, my application began giving me strange domain errors on startup.  No matter what I do I cannot get this to work.

```
Caused by MappingException: Could not determine type for: appospherelaunchv1.Entity, at table: entity_history, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(entity)]
```

EntityHistory Class:

```
    class EntityHistory {
    Entity entity
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    Boolean isCurrent
    Date changeDate

   static belongsTo = [entity: Entity]

   static constraints = {
        entityTypeID nullable:false
        startDate nullable:false
        endDate nullable:true
        changeDate nullable:false
        isCurrent nullable:true
   }
}
```

Entity Class:

```
class Entity {
String description
Date changeDate
Date createDate
Date entityChangeDate
EntityTypes entityTypes
User user
Customer customer
Contacts contacts
LeadSources leadSources
EntityStatus entityStatus

static hasMany = [entityData: EntityData]
static belongsTo = [entityTypes: EntityTypes, user: User, customer: Customer, contacts: Contacts, leadSources: LeadSources, entityStatus: EntityStatus]

   static constraints = {
        user nullable:false
        customer nullable:false
        contacts nullable:false
        leadSources nullable:false
        description size:1..2000, nullable:true
        entityTypes nullable:false
        changeDate nullable:false
        createDate nullable:false
        entityStatus nullable: false
        }
}
```

Removing the belongs to entity relationship does not change the error message.  Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: Can you try creating in a new database instance?

Comment: From my experience, if you have the entity defined in a `belongsTo`, you don't have to explicitly define it separately, as well.  If you keep `Entity entity` in your `EntityHistory` domain, you should only have to state `belongsTo = Entity`.  If you remove `Entity entity`, you can keep `belongsTo = [entity: Entity]`.  However, since you've said removing the `belongsTo` altogether does't correct the problem, this may not be helpful.

Comment: What happened between _running fine_ and _strange domain errors_?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are already defining property in **belongsTo** of **EntityHistory** then no need to define the same as another property.

so try removing Entity entity from EntityHistory class as its not able to map same name property with your column in database.

Also it might already screwed up your database. Try running your application in a new DB instance with "create" mode in DataSource to create fresh new tables.

Thanks.